# what happens to WAL files when standby server is in recovery

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, write-ahead-logging

in the case where we have `SERVER1` (prod db) and `SERVER2` (hot standby), what happens to the WAL files from `SERVER1` when `SERVER2` goes into recovery mode and is opened?

On `SERVER1`, the `ARCHIVE_COMMAND` looks like this

```
test ! -f SERVER2:$PGDATA/pg_xlogArchive/%f && scp %p SERVER2:$PGDATA/pg_xlogArchive/%f
```

on `SERVER2`, the `RESTORE_COMMAND` looks like this

```
cp -f /vol2/postgres92/pgsql/data/pg_xlogArchive/%f /vol2/postgres92/pgsql/data/pg_xlog
```

all works ok, and when the trigger file is created both `SERVER1` and `SERVER2` are available for writes. But as the `ARCHIVE_COMMAND` on `SERVER1` remains in place I was expecting the WAL files to continue to be shipped to `SERVER2` into the `SERVER2:$PGDATA/pg_xlogArchive/%f` location, but they aren't. So how does `SERVER1` know to stop shipping the logs?

thanks
Dave

Comment: In the first place, why do you promote the slave when the master is still running?  It is a recipe for disaster...

Comment: we have a process which can sometimes fail. So we want to try stopping the shipping of log files to slave before this process starts, then if there is a problem on live we can repoint our application back to the slave (which is now in a writable state with data from before the failover)

Comment: What does the server log file say?  Any messages about archive failure?

Comment: no, no messages of failure in the logs. Is my understanding correct in thinking at the logs should continue to be shiipped  but not applied?